# Alguém tem alguma informação sobre a Google não disponibilizar mais o ADT para download? Eles fixaram o Android Studio como ferramenta?

Tags: android, android-studio

Caso ja exista a pergunta me desculpem, mas fiz um app e publiquei esses dias.
Fui criar um novo projeto, de outra ideia, e o eclipse não criou a activity nem o layout, imaginei que estivesse desatualizado. Logo atualizei tudo no SDK manager.
Mesmo assim nada. Fui no site baixar o novo, e não achei o ADT. Apenas o Android Studio. Alguém tem alguma informação sobre isso?
Pois estou cogitando mudar de plataforma depois dessa, sim sei, ja passou da hora. Mas tenho projetos em desenvolvimento no eclipse e nem toda migração de ferramenta é simples assim né.

Enfim, alguém tem alguma informação, de preferência com fonte confiável sobre isso ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Sim, o *Google* esta promovendo o Android Studio como alternativa para o desenvolvimento Android ao Eclipse. Isso pode ser visto de várias formas: 1) O menu do **Android Studio** é o segundo na sessão de ferramentas 2) A tela inicial da sessão **Tools** tem uma propaganda enorme sobre o **Android Studio**. 3) Eles recomendam a migração diversas vezes. Na página http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html você encontra mais infos para baixar: Ou pelo **Install New Software** ou com o **zip** que fica no final da página.

Comment: Bacana. Valeu pela informação ai. Abraço

Answer (score 1):

Nunca vi uma nota oficial e creio que não haveria por parte da Google por enquanto, até para não assustar os desenvolvedores.

Porém, é o que se pode notar é vestígios de um possível abandono da continuação do ADT para o Eclipse como por exemplo:

> Note: Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) is no longer supported with the latest version of ADT.

Outra abordagem:

> If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates.

Esses trechos foram tirados do http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Em relação a sua questão, você não passou da hora de migrar seu desenvolvimento para o Android Studio, mas, acredito que quando você for iniciar o desenvolvimento no AndroidStudio você irá ver grandes mudanças, é para melhor. Pois estou utilizando o Android Studio para desenvolvimento, e a cada dia que passa, descubro algo ainda mais fascinante que no Eclipse não temos.

Espero ter ajudado.
Boa sorte!

Comment: Gustavo, realmente esses detalhes eu cheguei a reparar. E tendo tudo isso eu passei a utilizar mais o Android Studio e não tenho do que reclamar. =D

Comment: Você vai se surpreender cada vez mais! No inícios, todos os dias eu descobria um atalho, uma função nova. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

[Plugin ADT](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Espero que seja isso que você procura.